# Where is rabbitmqctl on macos?

Tags: macos

I have installed rabbitmq on my mac.

Unfortunately `rabbitmqctl` is not available on the command line.

```
$ rabbitmqctl list_queues
-bash: rabbitmqctl: command not found
```

Comment: Where did you install it from, source, package manager...?

Comment: Yes, I used homebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed from [Homebrew](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-homebrew.html) you can find the the RabbitMQ server scripts and CLI tools installed in `sbin` directory under `/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq`, which is accessible via `/usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/sbin`. In case that directory is not in `PATH` it's recommend to append it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/sbin
```

Comment: One small change is in my case there was a version number: `/usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.7.16/sbin`

Answer (score 0):

update for 2022:
On my version, it is here:
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.10.7/sbin/rabbitmqctl`
where `3.10.7` is the version of your `rabbitmq`
so you add this line
`PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rabbitmq/3.10.7/sbin/`
to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).